# Improve Slow Mysql Query

Tags: mysql

i have a database table containing events.

```
mysql> describe events;
+-------------+------------------+------+-----+---------------------+----------------+
| Field       | Type             | Null | Key | Default             | Extra          |
+-------------+------------------+------+-----+---------------------+----------------+
| device      | varchar(32)      | YES  | MUL | NULL                |                |
| psu         | varchar(32)      | YES  | MUL | NULL                |                |
| event       | varchar(32)      | YES  | MUL | NULL                |                |
| down_time   | timestamp        | NO   | MUL | CURRENT_TIMESTAMP   |                |
| up_time     | timestamp        | NO   | MUL | 0000-00-00 00:00:00 |                |
| id          | int(10) unsigned | NO   | PRI | NULL                | auto_increment |
+-------------+------------------+------+-----+---------------------+----------------+
6 rows in set (0.01 sec)
```

i want to find events that overlap in time and use the following query:

```
SELECT *

FROM link_events a 
JOIN link_events b 

ON  ( a.down_time <= b.up_time )
AND ( a.up_time >= b.down_time )

WHERE (a.device = 'd1' AND b.device = 'd2')
AND   (a.psu = 'p1' AND b.psu = 'p2')
AND   (a.event = 'e1' AND b.event = 'e2');

+-------------+-----------+------------+---------------------+---------------------+--------+-------------+-----------+------------+---------------------+---------------------+--------+
| device      | psu       | event      | down_time           | up_time             | id     | device      | psu       | event      | down_time           | up_time             | id     |
+-------------+-----------+------------+---------------------+---------------------+--------+-------------+-----------+------------+---------------------+---------------------+--------+
| d1          | p1        | e1         | 2013-01-14 16:42:10 | 2013-01-14 16:43:00 | 374529 | d2          | p2        | e2         | 2013-01-14 16:42:14 | 2013-01-14 16:42:18 | 211570 |
| d1          | p1        | e1         | 2013-05-29 18:49:26 | 2013-05-30 12:31:15 | 374569 | d2          | p2        | e2         | 2013-05-30 08:48:20 | 2013-05-30 08:48:27 | 211787 |
| d1          | p1        | e1         | 2013-05-29 18:49:26 | 2013-05-30 12:31:15 | 374569 | d2          | p2        | e2         | 2013-05-30 08:48:54 | 2013-05-30 08:48:58 | 211788 |
+-------------+-----------+------------+---------------------+---------------------+--------+-------------+-----------+------------+---------------------+---------------------+--------+
3 rows in set (35.88 sec)
```

The events table contains the following number of rows:

```
mysql> select count(*) from events;
+----------+
| count(*) |
+----------+
|   977759 |
+----------+
1 row in set (0.01 sec)

mysql> select count(*) from events where device = 'd1' and psu = 'p1' and event = 'e1';
+----------+
| count(*) |
+----------+
|    11397 |
+----------+
1 row in set (0.12 sec)

mysql> select count(*) from events where device = 'd2' and psu = 'p2' and event = 'e2';
+----------+
| count(*) |
+----------+
|      243 |
+----------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

The database is installed on Windows 7 laptop and uses MyISAM engine.
Is there a way to better organise the database or change indexing to 
improve query time which for first query is 35 secs. Repeating the 
same query gives an immediate result however if i 'flush tables' and 
repeat query a third time the time taken is again 35 secs. 
Any help appreciated !

Here is output from EXPLAIN after ADD KEY:

```
mysql> EXPLAIN
    -> SELECT *
    ->
    -> FROM link_events a
    -> JOIN link_events b
    ->
    -> ON       ( a.down_time <= b.up_time )
    -> AND      ( a.up_time >= b.down_time )
    ->
    -> WHERE (a.device = 'd1' AND b.device = 'd2')
    -> AND (a.psu = 'l1' AND b.psu = 'l2')
    -> AND (a.event = 'e1' AND b.event = 'e2');
+----+-------------+-------+------+--------------------------------------------------------------------------------+---------------+---------+-------------------+------+-----------------------+
| id | select_type | table | type | possible_keys                                                                  | key           | key_len | ref               | rows | Extra                 |
+----+-------------+-------+------+--------------------------------------------------------------------------------+---------------+---------+-------------------+------+-----------------------+
|  1 | SIMPLE      | b     | ref  | device,psu,event,down_time,up_time,device_2,device_3                           | device_2      | 297     | const,const,const |  180 | Using index condition |
|  1 | SIMPLE      | a     | ref  | device,psu,event,down_time,up_time,device_2,device_3                           | device_2      | 297     | const,const,const | 7744 | Using index condition |
+----+-------------+-------+------+--------------------------------------------------------------------------------+---------------+---------+-------------------+------+-----------------------+
2 rows in set (0.07 sec)
```

New column:

```
mysql> describe link_events;
    +-------------+------------------+------+-----+---------------------+-----------------------------+
    | Field       | Type             | Null | Key | Default             | Extra                       |
    +-------------+------------------+------+-----+---------------------+-----------------------------+
    | device_name | varchar(32)      | YES  | MUL | NULL                |                             |
    | link_name   | varchar(32)      | YES  | MUL | NULL                |                             |
    | event_type  | varchar(32)      | YES  | MUL | NULL                |                             |
    | down_time   | timestamp        | NO   | MUL | CURRENT_TIMESTAMP   | on update CURRENT_TIMESTAMP |
    | up_time     | timestamp        | NO   | MUL | 0000-00-00 00:00:00 |                             |
    | span        | geometry         | NO   | MUL | NULL                |                             |
    | id          | int(10) unsigned | NO   | PRI | NULL                | auto_increment              |
    +-------------+------------------+------+-----+---------------------+-----------------------------+
    7 rows in set (0.03 sec)
```

EXPLAIN:

```
mysql> EXPLAIN
    ->
    ->  SELECT
    ->
    ->  CONCAT('Link1','-', 'Link2') overlaps,
    ->  GREATEST(a.down_time,b.down_time) AS downtime,
    ->  LEAST(a.up_time,b.up_time) AS uptime,
    ->  TIME_TO_SEC(TIMEDIFF( LEAST(a.up_time,b.up_time),
    ->          GREATEST(a.down_time,b.down_time))) AS duration
    ->
    ->  FROM link_events a
    ->  JOIN link_events b
    ->
    ->  ON      Intersects (a.span, b.span)
    ->
    ->  WHERE (a.device_name = 'd1' AND b.device_name = 'd2')
    ->  AND (a.link_name = 'l1' AND b.link_name = 'l2')
    ->  AND (a.event_type = 'e1' AND b.event_type = 'e1');
    +----+-------------+-------+------+-------------------------------------------------------------------+---------------+---------+-------------------+-------+------------------------------------+
    | id | select_type | table | type | possible_keys                                                     | key           | key_len | ref               | rows  | Extra                              |
    +----+-------------+-------+------+-------------------------------------------------------------------+---------------+---------+-------------------+-------+------------------------------------+
    |  1 | SIMPLE      | a     | ref  | span,device_name,link_name,event_type,device_name_2,device_name_3 | device_name_2 | 297     | const,const,const |   383 | Using index condition              |
    |  1 | SIMPLE      | b     | ref  | span,device_name,link_name,event_type,device_name_2,device_name_3 | device_name_2 | 297     | const,const,const | 14580 | Using index condition; Using where |
    +----+-------------+-------+------+-------------------------------------------------------------------+---------------+---------+-------------------+-------+------------------------------------+
    2 rows in set (0.09 sec)
```

Using Intersects takes 1min 12 secs?

Comment: Flush tables clears the cache, hence it takes the same time again after calling. Most likely if you change the data or do some other queries it will take a long time again.

Comment: I find SHOW CREATE (or just the DDL) more useful than DESCRIBE

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try:

```
ALTER TABLE link_events ADD KEY(device,psu,event,up_time),
  ADD KEY(device,psu,event,down_time)
```

Hopefully this will be selective enough. If this does not help, post the results of `EXPLAIN` so we can make sure the optimizer is doing the best it can, and we will go from there if needed.

Edit:

It is important to understand that not all indexes are of equal value for a particular query. A common mistake is to think of an index as some magic worker that will automatically speed up the query if you just reference the column in the index. This is not quite the case. The keys need to be designed and the queries needs to be written in such a way that allows the best possible access path to the records. Changing something that might appear insignificant such as the order of the columns in the index or writing `SQRT(x) = 4.4` instead of `x = 4.4 * 4.4` could make the index unusable and slow the query down by a factor of a thousand or even a million or more.

I highly recommend reading this:

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/mysql-indexes.html

Having a feel for how MySQL uses keys can save you a lot of trouble in the future.

EDIT 2 - another idea is to add a column `span GEOMETRY NOT NULL, SPATIAL KEY (span)` containing `linestring(point(up_time,0),point(down_time,0))` - times would need to be numeric (you can convert using `UNIX_TIMESTAMP()` for example) - and use `Intersects(a.span,b.span)` in the query. With some fine tuning this has the potential of being much faster than even the improved query because span intersections are being detected using a geometry-based algorithm specially designed for such things.

Comment: That makes a huge difference Sasha query time now 8.6 secs. i have posted EXPLAIN after applying ADD KEY.
I had created index for these fields but had not made them KEY.

Comment: @user2149346 I don't understand what that means. ?!?!

Comment: hi Strawberry ..I initially created link_events without index on device, psu, event,down_time,up_time. In order to speed up query i decided to add indexes and issued:    ALTER TABLE link_events ADD INDEX (device,psu,event,down_time,up_time); But this did not speed up query.As suggested by Sasha i then added:

ALTER TABLE link_events ADD KEY(device,psu,event,down_time,up_time),
  ADD KEY(device,psu,event,down_time,up_time)

This improved the query from 35 secs to 8.5 secs

Comment: i do not understand why this was required as i thought adding index command would suffice??

Comment: i have added span column as you suggested. it works but slower !. i have posted the results of EXPLAIN ..many thanks for your help.

Comment: Index and key are synonyms @user2149346

Answer (score 4):

For this query:

```
SELECT *
FROM link_events a JOIN
     link_events b 
     ON  (a.down_time <= b.up_time) AND (a.up_time >= b.down_time)
WHERE (a.device = 'd1' AND b.device = 'd2') AND
      (a.psu = 'p1' AND b.psu = 'p2') AND
      (a.event = 'e1' AND b.event = 'e2');
```

You want indexes on `link_events(device, psu, event, up_time, down_time)`.  For clarity, I would express the query more like this:

```
SELECT *
FROM link_events a JOIN
     link_events b 
     ON  (a.down_time <= b.up_time) AND (a.up_time >= b.down_time)
WHERE (a.device, a.psu, a.event) IN (('d1', 'p1', 'e1')) AND
      (b.device, a.psu, a.event) IN (('d2', 'p2', 'e2'));
```

Comment: I would suggest you want one index all 5 columns. I think that would be best in this case.

Comment: many thanks had added index to fields but not made them KEY ..this has improved query time from 36 sec to 8.6 sec